# how can I use showChoiceDialog() in my main.dart file

Tags: flutter, dart, imagepicker

here is code of imagepicker in flutter .

how can I use **showChoiceDialog(), opengallery() ,openCamera()** in my other files . what class objects and variable should i have to make in order to use this functions in other file .how can I use **showChoiceDialog(), opengallery() ,openCamera()** in my other files . what class objects and variable should i have to make in order to use this functions in other file .

how can i set new image to Image Widgets .how can update the state.

imagepicker.dart

```
import 'dart:ffi';
import 'dart:io';

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:image_picker/image_picker.dart';

class CameraWidget extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  State createState() {
    // TODO: implement createState
    return CameraWidgetState();
  }
}

class CameraWidgetState extends State {
  PickedFile? imageFile = null;
  Future<void> showChoiceDialog(BuildContext context) {
    return showDialog(
      context: context,
      builder: (BuildContext context) {
        return AlertDialog(
          title: Text(
            "Choose option",
            style: TextStyle(color: Colors.blue),
          ),
          content: SingleChildScrollView(
            child: ListBody(
              children: [
                Divider(
                  height: 1,
                  color: Colors.blue,
                ),
                ListTile(
                  onTap: () {
                    _openGallery(context);
                  },
                  title: Text("Gallery"),
                  leading: Icon(
                    Icons.account_box,
                    color: Colors.blue,
                  ),
                ),
                Divider(
                  height: 1,
                  color: Colors.blue,
                ),
                ListTile(
                  onTap: () {
                    _openCamera(context);
                  },
                  title: Text("Camera"),
                  leading: Icon(
                    Icons.camera,
                    color: Colors.blue,
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
        );
      },
    );
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    // TODO: implement build
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text("Pick Image Camera"),
        backgroundColor: Colors.green,
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: Container(
          child: Column(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceAround,
            children: [
              Card(
                child: (imageFile == null)
                    ? Text("Choose Image")
                    : Image.file(File(imageFile!.path)),
              ),
              Image.asset('images/img1.jpg'),
              MaterialButton(
                textColor: Colors.white,
                color: Colors.pink,
                onPressed: () {
                  showChoiceDialog(context);
                },
                child: Text("Select Image"),
              )
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  void _openGallery(BuildContext context) async {
    final pickedFile = await ImagePicker().getImage(
      source: ImageSource.gallery,
    );
    setState(() {
      imageFile = pickedFile!;
    });

    Navigator.pop(context);
  }

  void _openCamera(BuildContext context) async {
    final pickedFile = await ImagePicker().getImage(
      source: ImageSource.camera,
    );
    setState(() {
      imageFile = pickedFile!;
    });
    Navigator.pop(context);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot access their properties as they are marked as private. To mark a function/method as private, you put an underscore before its name. For example, `checkUpdates()` is a public method, and `_checkUpdates()` is a public method.

I would recommend putting these in another file if you plan on reusing them.

A very basic method of doing this is to create a new file, `image_service.dart`

Make a new class

```dart
class ImageService {

 static void openGallery(BuildContext context) async {
    final pickedFile = await ImagePicker().getImage(
      source: ImageSource.gallery,
    );
    setState(() {
      imageFile = pickedFile!;
    });

    Navigator.pop(context);
  }

  static void openCamera(BuildContext context) async {
    final pickedFile = await ImagePicker().getImage(
      source: ImageSource.camera,
    );
    setState(() {
      imageFile = pickedFile!;
    });
    Navigator.pop(context);
  }
}
```

And then you can use it as follows. `ImageService.openGallery(context);`

Comment: i will make functions public but how can i use showChoiceDialog() in other file?

Comment: @PARANJAY I updated the post, please have a look.